# UIImagePickerController Camera Reappears after Being Dismissed - Memory

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, storyboard, uiimagepickercontroller

After setting up a UIImagePickerController camera I try to dismiss it with the following code :

```
- (void)doneButtonClick: (id)sender {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated : NO completion NO];
}
```

However the view just reloads itself and view will appear is called again. I think the app is receiving a memory warning and pulling down the non-visible views.

I want to reload the previous view as a solution. The previous view is a storyboard, so I am trying the following :

```
- (void)doneButtonClick:(id)sender {
//[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NO];
UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
BSPRoomDefaultViewController * myVC = (BSPRoomDefaultViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"default"];
[self presentViewController:myVC animated:YES completion:NO];

}
```

However I am getting an error that "attempt to present on whose view is not in the window hierarchy !"

Can anyone suggest how I can reload the previous view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone else, the problem is that presenting a full screen camera view nearly always generates a memory warning. This leads to the underlaying views being pulled down. Therefore the current view just re-loads when dismissed. The solution was to manually re-load the dealloced views.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using [self dismissViewControllerAnimated : NO completion NO]; use:

```
[imagePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

with imagePicker being your instance of UIImagePickercontroller.